# Rails 6 deployment as development is effected as production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Having a clean slate with an application being deployed to a new VPS, I gradually stumbled upon some oddities.

- log structures were definitely not of development mode type.
- logs were being written to both `development.log` and `production.log`.
- Errors communicated to the browser also confirmed that the application was running in production mode.

This is unexpected after calling

```
cap development deploy
```

`deploy.rb` was purposefully set as follows:

```
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/mark'
# target: production
```

and `deploy/development.rb` ( *why have deploy/development.rb if one has to specify environmente somewhere else? un-DRY* ) has the ip address of the VPS to which it is effectively deploying (production has none), and nothing else:

```
 server 'XXX.YYY.ZZZ.28', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{db web app}
```

Passenger, via `/etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf` has

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

So passenger routing does not seem to be at issue.

Thus capistrano is deploying under the guise of development, but materially producing a production mode... to database `mark_development`

Capfile has

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.1'
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

What is a) going on?  and  b) how can a deployment be made proper for development mode ?

Comment: Capistrano does not set the environment, passenger does. In the passenger config do you have some lines with: `passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production; ` ? Is rails_env set as development?

Comment: no, those are not effectively present.  Only those two lines shown.  THere is no `/etc/nginx/passenger.conf`

Comment: Not the config file, but in `server {...}` block, do you have them? Something like `server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name test;

  root PATH_TO_PUBLIC;

  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env development;`

Comment: Right.  bingo!   numerous other distractions leading to face-palm.

Comment: What @razvans said is correct excepting `rails_env` should be `passenger_app_env` I believe and also `capistrano` does "set an environment" for the deployment commands based on the stage which may be set or inferred from the deployment name (very DRY). `capistrano` does not "set the environment" that the actual application will launch under...

Comment: ...e.g. "deploy/development.rb" without a defined stage will run the commands against the development database and follow development environment configurations (i.e. no precompile etc) however passenger is what actually manages the application launch so it sets the environment for application execution.